# Split regex in Scala keeping delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string, scala

I'm trying to split a string using Regex with some rules:

- The string should be split into 2 with the the first part containing at least 2 characters
- The second part is made up of all characters starting with the first number (after the second character)

e.g. AB1234 = AB and 1234 , C56789 = C5 and 6789 , ZYX3939Y = ZYX and 3939Y

I have this Regex which is nearly working, but it loses the character it is splitting on:

`val t = request.number.split("(?<=.{2})[0-9]{1}", 2)`

`println(t(0), t(1))`

Gives:

`(AB,234)
(C5,789)
(EZY,9393Y)`

What is the correct regex and is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Check http://ideone.com/3YDnvc. How long are those codes?

Comment: What about something like "(.{2,}?)([\d].*)".r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off using `span` and `splitAt` methods on `String`.

```
val (twoFirst, rest) = request.number.splitAt(2)
val (noNumber, tail) = rest.span(!_.isDigit)
(twoFirst + noNumber, tail)
```

The first `val` splits the input after the second character.
The second `val` splits the input as soon as it finds a digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regexp `(.{2,}?)([\d].*)`

The first part matches any two characters, but tries to match shortest sequence possible (`?`) and then the next part first looks for a number (`\d`) followed by anything.